# General sibling selector not applying on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, siblings

Im trying to make a div disappear when hovering another one. Im trying to modify the width of the second div to 0 to make it disappear. However, the effect is not applying forit. Im using the general sibling selector (~)

```
<div id="bands">
<div id="left_band">
</div>
<div id="right_band">
</div>
```

```
#bands{
width: 960px;
height: 1000px;
background-color:  #002A66;
padding-top: 20px;
```

}

```
#left_band {
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
background-color: red;
```

}

```
#left_band:hover{
width: 900px;
height: 500px;
```

}

```
#right_band{
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: right;
background-color: red;
```

}

```
#right_band:hover ~ #left_band{
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
display: none;
```

}

Comment: which will only select siblings after the selector , not before

Answer (score 1):

According to this one:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector

you will need to interchange the order in your declaration:

```
#left_band~#right_band:hover{
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
transition: 0.5s ease;
display: none;
}
```

since left band comes first in your dom